# Error shown Missing $ inserted. even if it does not make sense

Tags: math-mode

I have is statement
R_{AB} $=$ \begin{bmatrix}

It is showing Missing $ inserted. I have no idea about it is there anyone who can help out please

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) The elements `R_{AB}` and `\begin{bmatrix}` should be called inside a math environment. Therefore, your statement should be `$R_{AB} = \begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}$`.

Comment: A side note: instead of plain TeX $ it is useful to use \( and \) to better troubleshoot these issues

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio that would not help in this case as the offending code is outside math mode.